# Adding Sorting to Website?

Tags: sort

I would like to add sorting but don't have any idea how ot go about it.  I would like to be able to sort by:

> Date, Title, Price (custom field), Comments, Views, ASC + DESC

What would be the best way to do something like this?

Comment: Check if this could help you - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57850/17968

Comment: can you paste more information like the loop of the page / post where you want to add sorting

Comment: @SagiveSEO like what?

Comment: @amit i tried http://site.com/?orderby=title&order=dsc and it went the the blog page and sorted.. this is a custom post type how do i get it to sort on the same page?

Comment: you can pass an extra parameter `post_type`, See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57862/17968) answer for custom post type support.

For a custom post type you can pass an extra parameter *( `post_type` )* to url, example -

```
www.example.com/?post_type=FOO&orderby=title&order=dsc
```

**Note -** If you've specified some url rewrite for that post type then the above url will become something like this but still showing all posts of post type `FOO` with descending order by title.

```
www.example.com/FOO/?&orderby=title&order=dsc
```

Comment: this works, but is there any php I can add for sorting? I only got it to work by trying `<a href="http://site.com/?post_type=portfolio&orderby=title&order=dsc">test</a>`

Comment: I didn't get you ? Do you want get this done without using url parameters ? I think this is best way to make posts sortable using a click.